# OAuth2 which flow to use for frontend to api to oauth communication/authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization

I am reading and reading, not sure why it's so hard to properly understand OAuth2 flows, which I thought I understand, until I wanted my own server.

So I have Frontend (web + mobile app aka resource owner), my own API server ( resource server )
and I want to create my own OAuth2 server.

1. So assuming, that on user registration, I am registering them on my OAuth2 server, saving username and hashed password ( I also want to save organization/project name, so I can user oauth2 server for multiple projects without worry of username duplicates)
2. Then Frontend obtains access+refresh tokens from OAuth2 server directly with password_grant. Or should I do it through my API and use CLIENT_ID/CLIENT_SERCRET with it (is that even an option)?
3. With access token, Frontend then now can communicate do my API(resource server)
4. API (resource server) then communicates with OAuth2 to validate access token - here I am not sure what's the common name of that action authorize or authenticate ?
5. Once access token is expired, Frontend (resource owner) can communicate directly to OAuth2 to obtain new access and refresh token. Or again - it should go through API and do it with CLIENT_ID/SECRET ?

Currently I did above implementation, but inside my API, but idea of OAuth2 is  that it is separated server. Not sure how it will benefit me other than I will be able to use it for other project, but I guess with OAuth2 I can then expose API to public.

Question is, is above correct ? can someone help me wrap it with correct OAuth2 terminology ?

Answer (score 1):

The frontend apps are not resource owners, but clients. Resource owners are users of these apps. These apps are so called public clients - they don't have a secure storage for their client secret, so they must not have a client secret. Instead, they should use [PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) (kind of one-time password) with the the auth code flow.

This way, they receive a refresh token they can use to get valid access tokens. The frontend apps use access tokens to authorize their requests to your backend. Your backend should validate them.

For more info, please see the current best practices - [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) and [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252).